# Customizing the list of figures (LOF) style using tufte-latex

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tufte

I'm using the [tufte-latex](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) class and would like to change the List of Figures style. When choosing the `\tableofcontents` I supply the `notoc` argument so that it uses the standard `LaTeX` style:

```
\documentclass[justified, notoc, symmetric]{tufte-book}
```

Is there a similar command to override the `LOF`? I did try:

```
\documentclass[justified, notoc, nolof, symmetric]{tufte-book}
```

but it did not seem to change them.
To illustrate the differences, here is the Table of Contents:

[image]

and here is the List of Figures:
[image]

The other customization that I wanted was for the numbers to be hyperlinked, instead of the text. I'm not sure if that is possible to easily do, though so I may just make all of the hyperlinks black instead. I'm using the following command for the hyperlink colors `\hypersetup{colorlinks}`.

The final customization, is that I wanted hyperlinks to websites to appear in another color. I can't figure out where to tweak that. Usually I use the `hyperref` package, but `tufte-latex` already chose colors using the `colorlinks` arguement. Is there a way that I can edit these options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two last requirements are achieved through the `linktocpage` and `urlcolor=<color>` options for `hyperref`. The first requirement can be obtained with a redefinition of the internal command `\l@figure` to behave as in the standard `book` document class. A little example:

```
\documentclass[justified, notoc, symmetric]{tufte-book}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage,urlcolor=red}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test section One}
\href{http://www.texstackexchange.com/}{TeX.SX}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{Test figure one}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\caption{Test figure two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Some images of the ToC, the LoF, and of the first chapter to see the hyperlink:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: oh, wow! Thank you. I just tested it out, and am curious how to make two minor modifications. The first is that for a long figure title, a line is skipped underneath. The second, is how can I add `dots` to run from text to the number?

Comment: @celenius 1) I need to see a sample document showing the undesired behaviour. 2) For the LoF for the ToC, for both of them? With these new requirements, we have already 5 questions in one! Next time, please open more than one question, focusing on few issues on each one.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I'm getting carried away. Do you think I should move the LoF question to be a separate question completely?

Comment: @celenius: next time... in the meantime I have some new code; I'll edit my question in the next seconds...